# Ajax request not sending in IE. 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I've seen lots of questions about problems with ajax and IE but i haven't found one like this..

The environment is Bootstrap / jQuery / Ajax / parsley / IE-11

I have an ajax script that is working in firefox and chrome.  In IE 11, the script will not send... it jumps right to the fail section. It's supposed to pop-up a bootstrap modal with content. The modal pops-up, but it's empty.

the url of the ajax request is the same url as the page it's on...
it's an http request, not an https request.. it's to an internal web server that pings to a 192.168 address.

Ajax requests on an earlier version of this system  (between the same url's) that do NOT use bootstrap are working with no problem..

I've turned off all console.log(). didn't help.
I've turn off the server, and it didn't make a difference.. the request isn't getting there...

i've tried lowering all the security settings without going into the custom detail dialog.. no effect..

when i turn back on the console log for fail
i get: Request failed: [object Object] (the object is not clickable)

Something in ie is blocking the request..

```
<script>
var AjaxSubmit
$("#rbbutton, #ubbutton").click(function() {
   AjaxSubmit =  $(this).attr("value");
   return true;
});

$(function () {
  var serverScript = '#serverurl' ; // Server side script we will be calling
    $("#rb").submit(function(e) {
      var str      =  $('#rb').serialize();
      str          = str + '&ajaxfunction=IamBidding' + '&AjaxSubmit='+encodeURIComponent(AjaxSubmit);

    if (typeof console == "object") {
    }
     var request   = $.ajax({
       type     : "POST",
       url      : serverScript,
       data     : str,
       cache    : false,
       encode   : true
       });
  request.done(function(data) {
    $("#modalbidconfirm").html(data);
    $('#bidconfirmmodal').modal('show');
   });
  request.fail(function( data) {
    if (typeof console == "object") {
      console.log( "Request failed: " + data  );
    }
    $("#modalbidconfirm").html(data);
    $('#bidconfirmmodal').modal('show');
  });
  e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem was not in the javascript. the problem was in the html which i did not include in the question.

Firefox and chrome did not have a problem with the serverurl id being defined in a div.

IE would not work unless the serverurl was defined in an input.

```
<form class="form-inline bidding" ID="rb" name="IamBidding" ACTION="">
```

i changed this:

```
<div id="serverurl" value="http://sometingorother.com/?&ajaxfunction=IamBidding"></div>
```

to this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="serverurl" value="http://sometingorother.com/?&ajaxfunction=IamBidding" />
```

and the script works in all 3 browsers.